# Does anyone have examples of using graph theory/network science in the field of Business Intelligence?

Tags: social-network-analysis

A lot of examples for the use of graph theory revolve around either social networks (which I understand are useful for business intelligence) or scientific/biological application.

I am exploring the application of graph theory on business data. The current applications that I have identified are:

- Airport connections
- Delivery logistics - like the one eBay
  implemented
- Co-purchasing networks
- Website navigation
- Bank transfers

Can anyone provide links to studies or companies already using graph theory in this field?

Comment: Do you need explanations (e.g. about use-cases you mentioned) or just use-cases? Is it a "How" question or a "what" question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer :) This is a "what" question. What applications does graph theory have on business data?

Comment: Look at container shipping and port operations.